# XPath for attribute values ordered by referring elements?

Tags: xml, xpath

I've got an XML file that contains a list of items, with ID attributes, and a list of references to those IDs. I'd like to retrieve the referenced item for each item.

My sample XML file looks like this:

```
<test>
    <items>
        <item id="a" val="A" />
        <item id="b" val="B" />
        <item id="c" val="C" />
        <item id="d" val="D" />
        <item id="e" val="E" />
    </items>
    <refs>
        <ref id="c" />
        <ref id="b" />
        <ref id="b" />
    </refs>
</test>
```

I've tried the expression

```
/test/items/item[@id=/test/refs/ref/@id]/@val
```

but it doesn't really do what I want: it (obviously) returns the items [B, C] instead of [C, B, B].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

Cannot be done.

### XPath 2.0

```
for $i in //ref/@id return //item[@id=$i]/@val
```

will return `[C, B, B]` as requested.

Comment: Since I don't think Python's lxml supports anything above XPath 1.0, I guess I'll have to do it with multiple xpaths, then.